# JPEG image quality decreases on cross compile to raspberry pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm trying to use qtquick project on my raspberry pi.
I have a jpeg image on my project.
The problem is when I cross compiled the project to the raspberry the quality of the image is getting bad as on the picture below... ( Left hand side monitor is connected to the raspberry pi)

[image: My Screens]

How can I handle this problem ? From where I have to start ?

Comment: Questions about the Raspberry Pi and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that color depth for EGLFS on RPI had been set to 16-bits. You can explicitly change it by

```
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCE888=1
```

on your RPI console. You may also want to set it permanently by adding it to `/etc/profile`